# How can I combine classes on a button using .less?

Tags: css, less

I have this .less file for buttons:

```
 button {
        background: @button-background;
        color: @text;

        &.primary {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#79d858, #569e3d);
            border-color: #4a993e;
            color: white;
        }

        &.primary:hover {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#89e868, #66ae4d);
            border-color: #4a993e;
            color: white;
        }

        &.primary:active,
        &.primary:focus {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#99f878, #76be5d);
            border-color: #4a993e;
            color: white;
        }

    }
```

Can someone give me advice on how I can combine all the &.primary into one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```css
button {
    background: @button-background;
    color: @text;

    &.primary {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#79d858, #569e3d);
        border-color: #4a993e;
        color: white;

        &:hover {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#89e868, #66ae4d);
        }

        &:active, &:focus {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#99f878, #76be5d);
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eaNEE/97/)